# <bad ptr> Overloading + Operator

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, pointers

The debugger is giving me 'bad ptr' when I create a new string array in this constructor, but only when my overloading operator method creates a new MyString object... confused.

Here is my constructor

```
MyString::MyString()
{
     stringSize = 0;
     stringCap = 16;
     stringArray = new char[stringCap + 1];
     stringArray[0] = '\0';
}
```

Here is my overloading operator method

```
MyString operator+(const char* leftOp, const MyString& rightOp)
{
     MyString result; // new object used to store result
     result.stringSize = strlen(leftOp) + rightOp.stringSize;
     // if the string does not fit in the array
     if( result.stringSize > result.stringCap )
     {
         delete[] result.stringArray;
         result.stringCap = ( result.stringSize + 15 ) & ~15;
         result.stringArray = new char[result.stringCap + 1];
     }
     strcpy(result.stringArray, leftOp);
     strcat(result.stringArray, rightOp.stringArray);
     return result;
  }
```

Here is my copy constructor, which the debugger never gets too

```
MyString::MyString(const MyString& s)
{
    stringSize = s.stringSize;
    stringCap = s.stringCap;
    //stringArray[stringCap + 1];
    stringArray = new char[stringCap + 1];
    stringArray = s.stringArray;
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* does the compiler say?

Comment: In your copy-constructor `stringArray = s.stringArray;` is wrong. Use `strcpy` instead. See the edit in my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since from your code snippet, nothing seems wrong, my sixth sense tells me that you've NOT written copy-constructor, and are working with the default one generated by the compiler, or possibly `stringArray` is not a null-terminated string!

EDIT:

In your copy-constructor, this is wrong:

```
stringArray = s.stringArray; //wrong!
```

Use `strcpy` instead:

```
strcpy(stringArray, s.stringArray); //correct!
```

Make sure all your strings are null-terminated!

Comment: I wrote a copy constructor, but when i use the debugger it never reaches the copy constructor

Comment: @bluetickk : Maybe, you've written it incorrectly. Show us the code!

Answer (score 3):

Well, when this method returns, "result" is going to be copied and the original destructed. If the destructor deletes the array, and there isn't a smart copy constructor which ensures that the new copy includes a valid new array, then you're going to have problems.

But you said the *compiler* says something about a bad pointer -- where? What line?

Comment: the debugger says bad ptr as soon as this line is read
stringArray = new char[stringCap + 1];